# When overriding default create method in Django view,it is not calling to_internal_value() in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to override the default creation function in my `view.py`. But when I try to use `to_internal_value()` it does not serialize the data. It only performs `to_internal_value()` when I don't override the default create() in my `views.py`.

views.py

```py
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = ContactInformation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TemplatesSerializer
    #If this function is commented then everything works  
    #fine and to_internal_value() is called while serializing
    def create(self, request):
        contact = ContactInformation()
        contact.name = request.data['name']
        contact.address = request.data['address']
        contact.save()
        return JsonResponse(data=TemplatesSerializer(contact).data)
```

serializer.py

```py
class TemplatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        print('Printing from to_internal')
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        print('Printing from to_represent')
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = ContactInformation
        fields = '__all__'
```

model.py

```py
class ContactInformation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Comment: serializer_class takes an class, but you gave it an instance.  what happens if you drop the `()` at the end there

Comment: @Andrew I changed the instance to class by dropping the `()`. But the issue is still the same. I can not access the to_internal_value() if I override the `create()` in the `viewset`

Comment: I belive `to_internal_value` is called when processing incoming data.  You are passing an instance, so that method is never called (it is already an "internal" value).  Why do you expect that to be called, and why do you expect to do there?  this is normally a method that you use when writing `fields`.

Comment: Your object is empty. You are treating it as an empty dictionary and its not like this. You should pass the data directly to de `ContactInformation(ADD DATA HERE).`